# I'm trying to deploy my react app with vercel. I did every step in my terminal but at the end get error "Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, vercel

here are details of problem:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! Found: typescript@5.3.3
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   typescript@"^5.3.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer typescript@">= 2.7" from fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!     fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@"^6.5.0" from react-dev-utils@12.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-dev-utils
npm ERR!       react-dev-utils@"^12.0.1" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!         react-scripts@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (tsutils)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   react-scripts@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@4.9.5
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-12-07T15_39_01_419Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-12-07T15_39_01_419Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

I have updated my node, npm, ts to the lates version

Comment: Please use code blocks to paste formatted text. It's very difficult to read. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Looks like `create-react-app` still doesn't support TypeScript 5. You can move down to version 4, or try the workaround here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13080

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's check the peer dependencies of the `react-scripts@5.0.1` package:

```bash
$ npm view react-scripts@5.0.1 peerDependencies
{ react: '>= 16', typescript: '^3.2.1 || ^4' }
```

It means `react-scripts@5.0.1` package requires the `typescript@^3.2.1` or `typescript@^4` as its peer dependency. But you have `typescript@5.3.3` installed in your project. You will meet this error by using npm v7+, see [Peer dependencies](https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/#peer-dependencies)

There are two solutions:

1. Downgrade the `typescript` package to the compatible versions.

```bash
npm i typescript@^4 -S
```

2. Use [overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) configuration of `package.json`

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
  "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
  "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
  "@types/node": "^16.18.68",
  "@types/react": "^18.2.42",
  "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.17",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
  "typescript": "^5.3.3",
  "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
"overrides": {
  "react-scripts": {
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
},
```

See related issues: [issues#13080](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13080) and [issues#13259](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13259)

*P.S. The best solution is to post a PR to ask the maintainers to add more TS versions as peer dependencies. They may or may not change the code to work with TS v5+*